# How can I remove the underlines from my post array elements?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to find a simple solution.  I'm trying to loop through a $_POST array like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $value => $key)
{
    echo $value;        
}
```

The values that I get back are all chained together with underline character like this:

```
Element_one_Element_two_Element_Three_Element_Four_submit
```

How can I get the array to simply display each elements without the underline and the appropriate break like this:

```
Element one
Element two
Element three
Element four
```

Because I'm creating and sending the contents of the post array dynamically to the database I don't to use hard code like $_POST["someArrayElementName'];

Thanks for any help!

Comment: simply use a `<br>` tag at the end of `echo`.. `echo $value.'<br>';`

Comment: Words that have spaces between still have the underlines.

Comment: Rizier123 thanks for the solution!  That did work!

Comment: @CloudyKooper Glad that I could help you, converted it to a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just simply use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to change all underlines to spaces and at the end I append a new line tag)

```
echo str_replace("_", " ", $value) . "<br />";
```